# How to show that this series converges or diverges using LCT or CT?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left (\sqrt{n^4+1}-n^2\right)$$

The question states that either the limit comparison or comparison test can be used to determine whether the series converge or diverge. I tried finding a $B_n$ in order to test $\frac{A_n}{B_n}$ for the limit comparison but having trouble coming up with $B_n$ that I know will converge or diverge. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you read [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your maths text.

Comment: Also

$$\sqrt{n^{4} + 1} - n^{2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{4} + 1} + n^{2}} \le \frac{1}{n^{2}}$$

Comment: Thank you. Bookmarked link for next time.

Comment: @Mattos. $\sqrt{n^{4} + 1} - n^{2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{4} + 1} + n^{2}} \le \frac{1}{2n^{2}}$ could even be better for an upper bound of the sum.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You're right, I just tried to give the OP an upper bound that he/she might recognise easily (even though our bounds _look_ very similar and the OP could probably infer mine from yours).

Comment: @Mattos. I know that and the hint is very good, for sure ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\sqrt{n^4+1}-n^2 &=\dfrac{\sqrt{n^4+1}-n^2}{1} \\
&=\dfrac{\left(\sqrt{n^4+1}-n^2\right)\left(\sqrt{n^4+1}+n^2\right)}{\left(\sqrt{n^4+1}+n^2\right)} \\
&=\dfrac{\left(\sqrt{n^4+1}\right)^2-n^4}{\sqrt{n^4\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n^4}\right)}+n^2} \\
&=\dfrac{n^4+1-n^4}{n^2\,\sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{n^4}}+n^2} \\
&=\dfrac{1}{n^2\left(\sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{n^4}}+1\right)}
\end{align}

As $\sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{n^4}}\le 1,\ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have

$$\dfrac{1}{n^2\left(\sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{n^4}}+1\right)}\le \dfrac{1}{2n^2}$$

therefore the series converges because the greater series converges.

Comment: You seem to have switched a "$+$" for a "$-$". Once that is fixed, your last inequality is fine.

Comment: You also need to change "As $\sqrt{1+\frac1{n^4}}\ge1$, ..."

Comment: All we really need is $$ \begin{align} \sqrt{n^4+1}-n^2 &=\frac1{\sqrt{n^4+1}+n^2}\\ &\le\frac1{2n^2} \end{align} $$